# Firefox hang for 4 or 5 second when loading

Tags: 12.04, firefox

I am using Firefox 15 in ubuntu 12.04 but it hangs for 4 or 5 second the browser became dark when loading anything.

Comment: what's your PC configuration

Comment: My browser was working fine some days back. But it is hangs for the last two days. In between I also installed KDE 4.9. Okay, my specification is Intel Dual Core Processor 2.7 Ghz. 4 GB DDR3 RAM Nvidia Graphics.

Comment: This might be due to some add-on.Try running firefox in safe mode and see if the proble still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart Firefox without Add-on
 1. Go to Help Menu of Firefox
 2. Then select Restart with Add-On Disabled

After the Firefox restart check whether it still hangs or not. If it doesn't hang
 then restart normally

Then follows the steps :-

1. Then go to Tools menu
2. Then select Add-Ons
3. Then select Extensions
4. Then Disable Add-Ons by click the disable button on the right side one by one but don't forget to restart the firefox after disabling each time and check if it still hangs
5. If you find the problematic Add-Ons then enable all other add-ons except the   problematic one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 13.04, and it solved after I uninstalled
`unity-webapps-facebookapps` and `unity-webapps-youtube`

Comment: thank you very much for your help - i'm not very will in english, but i hope my answer help people they have the same problem.